# programming raspberry pi with C/C++ simd instructions

Tags: c, arm, c++

Is it possible to use C/C++ SIMD instructions in a program and run it on  a raspberry pi model b+ ?

The raspberry pi has an arm processor, and there's a C/C++ SIMD instructions set for the ARM architecture, but can one use these SIMD instructions in any arm processor (including that of the raspberry pi model b+)?

---

In order to test whether the raspberry pi model b+ supports SIMD instructions, I tried to execute a program containing an SIMD intrinsic:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int add_halfwords(unsigned int val1, unsigned int val2)
{
 unsigned int res;
 res = __qadd16(val1,val2);
 return res;
}
int main()
{
printf("%f\n",add_halfwords(2014,1)); 
return 0;
}
```

I used the function **add_halfwords()** from the **infocenter.arm.com** website.
However I got a compilation error from gcc:

```
simd_test1.o: In function `add_halfwords':
simd_test1.c:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `__qadd16'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

From what I experienced on the intel architecture, each SIMD instruction requires the inclusion of its relative library. I looked for the library which contains the definition of __qadd16() but I was enable to find any useful hint.
Has anyone any idea?

Comment: Why not just try?  I can't see much point on a single processor unit such as the Pi.  If you don't have a Pi could you post some code (plus instructions) and I'm sure someone will compile and run it for you.

Comment: Thank you joan for your comment. Indeed, I have to try to run some simd instructions on my pi. Is there another way to know whether a processor supports simd instructions?

Comment: Google?  I know nothing about SIMD but Google suggests it is first supported in the ARMv7 instruction set.  The Pi uses the ARMv6 instruction set.

Answer (score 0):

ARM's own site refers to [SIMD functionality for armv6](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0348c/BABCGGIF.html), which is the instruction set for the pi's processor.

It also claims if the platform doesn't support something, you should get a compiler error if you try.  I don't use asm, but this makes sense.

So there should not be any ambiguity.  If you confirm this one way or another for yourself, please come back and provide a better answer to your question!